# What is the name of this theme for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I came across this picture in [June 2020 (v1.47) Visual Studio Code update notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_single-view).

[image]

I tried to search for this theme, but did not find anything like it.

I think it might be the standard look and feel of Visual Studio Code on some Linux distribution (like Manjaro or other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for it. I found it: 
**Github sharp theme.** 
You can find it here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joaomoreno.github-sharp-theme